# Google Doc App Script Update Selected Text with New Text

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm trying to write an app script to replace the current text selection with a new AI generated text, via menu item.
The script will work fine but I cannot update the current selection, as I get the following error

TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'insertText')
at generateAndReplace(Codice:55:19)

I guess that this is due to the fact that selection is nothing to do with cursor position...

This is my script

```
  // Get the active Google Docs document and the user-selected text
  const doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  const userText = doc.getSelection().getRangeElements()[0].getElement().asText().getText();
  
  // Get the body of the document and the prompt for the OpenAI API request
  const body = doc.getBody();
  const prompt = doc.getSelection().getRangeElements()[0].getElement().asText().getText();

// Get the completion prompt from OpenAI API request
  generatedText = completion(prompt)  
  
  // log
  Logger.log(generatedText);

  var currentPosition = doc.getCursor();
 
  deleteSelectedText();
  currentPosition.insertText(generatedText.toString());

  return;

}
```

How can I replace the whole selection with a new text?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to replace the selected text with `generatedText = completion(prompt)`.
- Unfortunately, I cannot know your function `completion(prompt)`. But, your function `completion(prompt)` works fine.

#### Modification points:

- In your script, there are variables that are not used in the script.
- In the case of `var currentPosition = doc.getCursor()` and `currentPosition.insertText(generatedText.toString())`, the selected text cannot be used. I think that the reason for your current issue of `TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'insertText')` is due to this.
- In order to replace the selected text, it is required to use `getSelection()`.

When these points are reflected in the script, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

When you use this script, please select a text and run the script.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const selection = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getSelection();
  if (selection) {
    selection.getRangeElements().forEach(e => {
      const start = e.getStartOffset();
      const end = e.getEndOffsetInclusive();
      const prompt = e.getElement().asText();
      const generatedText = completion(prompt.getText()); // This is your function.
      prompt.deleteText(start, end);
      prompt.insertText(start, generatedText);
    });
  }
}
```

#### Testing:

For example, when `generatedText` of `const generatedText = completion("someText");` returns a text value of `sample`, the following result is obtained.

[image]

#### Note:

- When the text is not selected, even when the script is run, the script is not run. When you use this script, please select a text and run the script.
- In this sample script, it supposes that your function `completion("someText")` works fine. Please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [getSelection()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#getselection)
- [deleteText(startOffset, endOffsetInclusive)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#deleteText(Integer,Integer))
- [insertText(offset, text)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#inserttextoffset,-text)

### Added:

From your following reply,

> but I still get some error as the following const start = e.getStartOffset();           const end = e.getEndOffsetInclusive(); will return start=-1 and end=-1

I'm worried that your selected texts includes images. From your question of `replace the current text selection with a new AI generated text`, I thought that you want to replace the selected texts. If your selected texts includes images, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const selection = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getSelection();
  if (selection) {
    selection.getRangeElements().forEach(e => {
      const start = e.getStartOffset();
      const end = e.getEndOffsetInclusive();
      if (start == -1 && end == -1) {
        e.getElement().removeFromParent();
        return;
      }
      const prompt = e.getElement().asText();
      const generatedText = completion(prompt.getText()); // This is your function.
      prompt.deleteText(start, end);
      prompt.insertText(start, generatedText);
    });
  }
}
```

- This sample script removes the images included in the selected text. And, the text is replaced with `generatedText`.

Comment: thank you for your detailed response, but I still get some error as the following
        `const start = e.getStartOffset();
          const end = e.getEndOffsetInclusive();`
will return start=-1 and end=-1

Comment: @neting.it Thank you for replying. From your reply, I added one more sample script. Please confirm it.